# Compare List of items then split

Tags: c#

I have created 3 different list variable which will contains data for add,delete and update. I have to compare data with `ExistingItems` to `NewItemList` then if `ExistingItems` have a data but `NewItemList` not have then the item should be listed in `deleteList` variable. Like this way if `NewItemList` have a data but `ExistingItems` not have then the item should be listed in `addList`. And finally when `ExistingItems` `NewItemList` match it will be add to `updateList`. Please note the ID is unique to compare matching and `ExistingItems` and `NewItemList` both data models type is exactly same as `Item` class. I already tried to filter `addList` using Except() method but this wont work for me because i want to compare by only ID not Price.

Main Codes:

```
var addList = new List<Item>();
var updateList = new List<Item>();
var deleteList = new List<Item>();

addList = EixistingItems.Except(NewItemList).ToList();
```

Item Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestProj.Models
{
    Class Item 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The issue probably is in how you create your `ExisitingItems`/`NewItemList` Objects, but without code there is not much we can do to help you. Also `ExistingItems.Excep(NewItemList)` should be written to `deleteList` and not `addList`, no?

Comment: You can't create a `class` without using keyword `class`.

Comment: Class issue fixed

Comment: @johnCogdle No it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Thanks Freggar pointing out my mistake.
In case you are doing comparison between two same type object like in the OP question stated, `Except` is much more prefered. plori already provide the correct ans so I don't repeat it, and his ans should be chosen.

The only situation that should use `Where` with `Any` is, for example,

```
Class Item_1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

Class Item_2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int remark { get; set; }
}
```

As `Except` use `hashset` to save the item for comparison, in this case `Except` can no longer be used, and so on shift to use `Where` with `Any`.

**Original answer**

Try

```
var deleteList = ExistingItems.Where(ei => !NewItemList.Any(ni => ni.ID == ei.ID ));

var updateList = ExistingItems.Where(ei => NewItemList.Any(ni => ni.ID == ei.ID ));

var addList = NewItemList.Where(ni => !ExistingItems.Any(ei => ei.ID == ni.ID ));
```

Comment: I learn this quite a long time on stackoverflow before, I believe there should be an ans already. Thus, I believe this question is duplicate.

Comment: You really should use `Except` and `Intersect` like OP is trying to do. You are trying to do the same thing but your solution is just more inefficient and unclear in intention.

Comment: Nvm, about the compile part

Comment: I can't quite follow "iterating a IEqualityComparer is costly", a Comparer is not an iterator? A Comparer just says hey use my `Equals` and `GetHashCode` function instead of the object's one I don't see any inefficency here. But what you are basically doing is two nested `for` loops resulting in a quadratic like complexity. `Except` on the other hand uses two seperate for loops and a internal HashSet resulting in a linear like complexity (but also with linear space complexity). If your solution would be more efficient on average, LINQ would certainly use that for their `Except` implementation.

Comment: @Freggar, Ok, I apologize first as I mess up the concept. You are correct, using `Except` is much faster.  I did a program to test, while `Except` take O(n), and `where any` take O(n^2) as `Any` involved. I remember wrongly as -- When the comparison is made between two different type list, lets say one `item_1` and one `item_2`, `Except` will not work. I will make an amendment on this. Thanks.

Comment: no need to apologize, your original answer did not have any mistake in it per se, I just wanted to point out that there could be a performanc difference.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is an equality comparer. It allows to control comparison in the `Except` linq statement. You can then define to check the `ID` property only:

```
var deleteList = ExistingItems.Except(NewItemList, new ItemComparer()).ToList();
var addList = NewItemList.Except(ExistingItems, new ItemComparer()).ToList();

class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.ID == y.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```